# Why doesn't the Modifier of child element fit the Modifier of parent element in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I run either Code A1 or Code A2, and get the same result Image *A1A2*.

I run Code B, and get the result Image B.

I run either Code C1 or Code C2, and get the same result Image *C1C2*.

1: Either `Canvas( modifier = Modifier...` in `ScreenHome_Table` of Code A1 or `Canvas( modifier = parentModifier...` in `ScreenHome_Table` of Code A2 get the the same result, why? and why doesn't `Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()..` in `ScreenHome_Table` of Code A1 fill in full screen?

2: `Row( modifier = parentModifier.fillMaxSize(` in Code B expand child element to full screen of parent element, why ?

3: The Canvas in both Code C1 and Code C2 are disappeared, why?

**Code A1**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenHome(
    rootModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    ...
) {
    Scaffold(
        modifier = rootModifier.fillMaxSize(),
        ...            
    ) { paddingValues ->

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            ScreenHome_Watch(
                parentModifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(0.6f)
            )    
            ScreenHome_Info(
                parentModifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )    
            ScreenHome_Table(
                parentModifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(0.4f)
            )
        }
    }    
}

@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Watch(
    parentModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
){
    Box(
        modifier = parentModifier
            .background(color = Color.Yellow)
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Info(
    parentModifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    Row(
        modifier = parentModifier
                      .background(color = Color.Gray),
        verticalAlignment= Alignment.CenterVertically

    ){
        Text("Hello")
    }
}


@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Table(
    parentModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = parentModifier
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(color = Color.Green)
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

**Code A2**

```
//The other code is same as Code A1

@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Table(
    parentModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = parentModifier
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = parentModifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(color = Color.Green)
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

**Image A1A2**

[image]

**Code B**

```
//The other code is same as Code A1


@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Info(
    parentModifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    Row(
        modifier = parentModifier
                      .fillMaxSize()
                      .background(color = Color.Gray),
        verticalAlignment= Alignment.CenterVertically

    ){
        Text("Hello")
    }
}
```

**Image B**

[image]

**Code C1**

```
//The other code is same as Code A1

@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Table(
    parentModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = parentModifier
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier                       
                        .background(color = Color.Green) //The Canvas is disappear;
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

**Code C2**

```
//The other code is same as Code A1

@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Table(
    parentModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = parentModifier
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = parentModifier
                        .background(color = Color.Green) //The Canvas is disappear;
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

**Image C1C2**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using an instance of `Modifier` that you got as a parameter twice is something you definitely shouldn't do. In your case though, it behaves the same as if you'd use `Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(0.4f)` instead of `parentModifier` on the `Canvas`, since this modifier is stateless. Something like `Modifier.clickable`, on the other hand, would cause problems as it's statefull.

   - Why do you get same result for A1 and A2?
     Because in A2, Canvas ends up with this modifier:

     ```
     Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(0.4f).fillMaxSize().background()
     ```

     weight has no effect inside `Box` and `fillMaxWidth` is included in `fillMaxSize`, so it's the same as A1 with just `fillMaxSize`.
   - Why doesn't Canvas in A1 fill full screen?
     Modifier `fillMaxSize` respects the incoming measurement constraints as stated in its documentation, which means that it won't grow bigger than its parent Box. Modifier `requiredSize` on the other hand ignores incoming constraints, so child can outgrow its parent.
2. In addition to `fillMaxWidth` from parentModifier, you also used `fillMaxSize` on your `ScreenHome_Info`, which means it will try to fill max height as well. The only height constraints on `ScreenHome_Watch` and `ScreenHome_Table` are the weights. As per the `weight` documentation:

   > Size the element's height proportional to its weight relative to other weighted sibling elements in the Column. The parent will divide the vertical space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements and distribute it according to this weight.

   This means that `ScreenHome_Info` as the only unweighted child is measured first, takes all the space and nothing is left for the other two, so they are not visible.
3. There is no size modifier on the Canvas in C1. In C2, you reuse the parent modifier `fillMaxWidth().weight(0.4f)`, but again, weight has no effect inside of a Box, so in C2, Canvas only has width and no height. And when you don't specify size for Canvas, it's simply 0, as per the documentation:

   > You MUST specify size with modifier, whether with exact sizes via Modifier.size modifier, or relative to parent [...]

   This is also the reason why Canvas, unlike most (all?) of the other components, has the `modifier` parameter mandatory and not empty `Modifier` by default.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of C1 Canvas does not have height or width.

In the case of C2 the screenshot C1C2 is probably not what you get if you have passed in `Modifier.fillMaxSize().weight(0.4f)` as in A1 for `ScreenHome_Table`.

Your code in c2 this works but would not recommend using same parent `Modifier` for both box and canvas.